# How to get a extrude with alpha brush

Tags: sculpting

With the sculpting i have made a alpha brush and imported and applied but im getting rough and not perfect result of extruding. I have a reference videos regarding Zbrush. Can its possible to make this clean extruding with the alpha brush.

[Reference Video 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VeC6WEZzbTM)

[Reference Video 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dNUHjB4YK5c)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mTBq.jpg

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can i achieve those result seen in video in Blender and how. Any suggestion or help how it works.